# Parsing Fetch gives Invalid Offset

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Not sure what is going on here but my password_verify statement is returning an undefined offset.  In the DB password is a required field, it cannot be empty and I've already verified that at least 1 matching row was returned before trying to verify the password against the hash.  When I use a foreach loop before this statement and check the result variable it gives me the hashed password just fine, so I know that there is at least 1 value in the array.  But when I try to access $result[0] that is throwing an undefined offset for some reason.  Tried looking this up but couldn't find relevant information other than the error is simply stating that the array index is invalid, which again is impossible because I can check the result variable with a foreach and see the hashed password in there.

Also a second question I have since I am still learning PDO, when I remove PDO::FETCH_ASSOC from the fetch request I get duplicate entries in my result variable.  Why is that?

**Login.php**

```
<?php
    require "conn.php";

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $email = strtolower($email);
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT password FROM account WHERE email=:email");
    $stmt->bindParam(":email", $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $count = $stmt->rowCount(); // gets count of records found

    if($count > 0) {
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // gets resultset
        if(!password_verify($pass, $result[0])) {
            echo "2";
        } else
            echo "0";
    }
    else {
        echo "1";
    }
?>
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to count the rows, just test the result.

Comment: You're doing `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` but then referencing the row by index `$result[0]`

Comment: Sorry I am still learning PDO.  So what should I be doing to get the password from the result variable?  Also, if I don't reference result by index then it tells me that a string was expected but I gave an array instead when I try to echo the result variable.

Comment: You retrieved an associative array, so use `$result['password']`

Comment: The reason for the duplicates without FETCH_ASSOC is that PDO retrieves a row and creates an array with _both_ the associative array key `['password']` and the numeric array index `[0]` ([because its default is `FETCH_BOTH`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)) and would do so for every column in `SELECT`. There are very very few good reasons to do that. Best to just explicitly request the type you need.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Hmm no, I don't think I'd classify as a typo.

Comment: So even if I use password_verify against $result['password'] it still says the password is invalid.  Even though it IS the correct password lol.  I've even re-registered the account a number of times.

Comment: How wide is your password column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will save you some milliseconds but, you should fetch first, then test the result without an additional conditional statement. Since you're using `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` you should then use the column name as the identifier, rather than an index:

```
<?php
    require "conn.php";

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $email = strtolower($email);
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT password FROM account WHERE email=:email");
    $stmt->bindParam(":email", $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // just fetch

    if(!password_verify($pass, $result['password'])) { // note, column name as identifier, if the password is bad or the column is empty the test is valid
            echo "2";
    } else {
            echo "0";
    }
?>
```

In addition, `password_hash()` needs a column which is at least 60 characters wide. Anything less than that will result in a failing test.

Comment: Thank you so much, your advice on password_hash fixed the other issue!  I completely forgot that I re-created the table earlier today and when I did that I set the length of the field to 20 (which is the max password length for user input) and totally forgot that you have to leave that extra space for the hashing process.  I edited the DB and set the field from 20 to 75 and it works perfectly now, thank you so much.  Sorry to be a pain!

Comment: You're not a pain! Glad to be able to help!